# Substitutions with elements from a list with re.sub?

Tags: python, regex

What is the best way to perform substitutions with `re.sub` given a list? For example:

```
import re

some_text = 'xxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyy@zzzzzzzzz@'
substitutions = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
x = re.sub('@', lambda i: i[0] substitutions.pop(0), some_text) # this doesn't actually work
```

The desired output would be:

```
some_text = 'xxxxxxxONEyyyyyyyyyTWOzzzzzzzzzTHREE'
```

Comment: Note that if you actually looked at the error you got when you ran this code, you would see that it _precisely_ points out where the syntax error is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have a syntax error in your lambda:

```
>>> substitutions = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
>>> re.sub('@', lambda _: substitutions.pop(0), some_text)
'xxxxxxxONEyyyyyyyyyTWOzzzzzzzzzTHREE'
```

If you don't want to modify the list, you can wrap it an iterable.

```
>>> substitutions = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
>>> subs = iter(substitutions)
>>> re.sub('@', lambda _: next(subs), some_text)
'xxxxxxxONEyyyyyyyyyTWOzzzzzzzzzTHREE'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way (there's probably a better one, I don't really know Python) is to compile the regular expression, then use that `sub` instead:

```
import re

some_text = 'xxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyy@zzzzzzzzz@'
substitutions = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
pattern = re.compile('@')
x = pattern.sub(lambda i: substitutions.pop(0), some_text)
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/rHLMA)

Answer (score 1):

The code is *almost* correct, it needs a slight correction of a syntax error:

```
import re

some_text = 'xxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyy@zzzzzzzzz@'
substitutions = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
x = re.sub('@', lambda i: substitutions.pop(0), some_text) # the error was in the lambda function
```